# How would I determine the convergence of a series using the Comparison Test?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would I determine convergence, using the Comparison Test, with the sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+3n}}$$

I know how the tests work, but when it comes to roots I have no idea how to approach it. Which test would be the quickest and how would it work? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Compare with some $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$ using the limit comparison test. In order to choose the correct $\alpha$, think which power of $n$ intuitively appears in your expression.

Comment: Note that$$\frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+3n}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{n+1+\frac3n}}$$

Answer (score 5):

Notice $n\ge 1\implies n^3+n^2+3n\ \le\ n^3+n^3+3n^3\ \le\ 5n^3\ \le\ 9n^3$

Consequently $\dfrac{3n}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+3n}}\ge\dfrac{3n}{\sqrt{9n^3}}=\dfrac{3n}{3n\sqrt{n}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Since $\sum\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}$ diverges, so is the original series.

Such rough inequalities are often overlooked, yet they bring so much benefit...

Answer (score 2):

The comments by @user170231 and @Mark are very helpful. With @user170231's simplification $\frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+3n}}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{n+1+\frac3n}}$, we just have a constant in the numerator, which we can just factor out of the summation. Mark made a point that you should try to compare the expression against what I call a p-series. Remember that a p-series diverges if $p\geq1$ but converges if $0<p<1$. This makes $p=1$ a point of interest. In order to make a comparison to determine whether it converges or diverges, compute the expression for a few values of $n$. You'll find that for $n=1,2,3,4,5$ this expression simplifies to $\sqrt{5}$, $\sqrt{4+\frac{1}{2}}$, $\sqrt{5}$, $\sqrt{5+\frac{3}{4}}$, and $\sqrt{7+\frac{1}{2}}$, respectively. Now, for what values of $n$ is $\sqrt{n+1+\frac{3}{n}}>n$, if any? For what values is it less than $n$, if any?

A final thing worth noting is that a finite sum plus a convergent sum is convergent.

Comment: You shouldn't assume that user170231's comment will stay in place. But it should be easy to copy the relevant equation's Latex code with a right-click. Welcome to Math Stack.

Answer (score 2):

Test of convergence using [limit comparison test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20limit%20comparison,convergence%20of%20an%20infinite%20series):

Given $u_n= \frac{3n}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+3n}}$  and $v_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^3}}{\sqrt{n^3+n^2+3n}} =3$

Since $\sum_{n}v_n$ diverges so that $\sum_n u_n$